# How are Storage Objects created from a file on Object Storage Cloud?

Tags: object, cloud, storage, openstack, ceph

I am defining Objects broken down from a file to be stored in Object Storage Cloud, as Storage Objects.

What I know: 
I have read documents and papers about object storage cloud. Most of the time, the documents assume that storage objects from a file (to be stored) have been already created and rest of the storage process is mostly explained. A Storage Object is a container that has some fixed size data with a numeric ID and some metadata.

what I would like to know is:

1. "How" are those storage objects actually created?
2. What is the break down process of a file into multiple storage objects?
3. What metadata and minimum metadata is saved alongside each object?
4. What "key" is (extracted) required to later retrieve that storage object?
5. Where is this "key" stored? -- (best if answered in the context of Ceph Object Storage technology)

Comment: When you say that a file is broken down into multiple storage objects, are you referring to how a POSIX file (e.g. /home/user/foo.txt) is stored in objects in the distributed storage system?